# My custom made mobile manipulator using Husky doesnt move

Tags: gazebo, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been stuck on this issue for the past one week.I mounted a custom made arm on top of a husky.Independently the arm and husky works fine without including each other.I am able to move the arm using moveit! and move the husky using the husky control package.

When i attach the arm on top of the husky my problem starts.I noticed the following.

```
  <gazebo>
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
  <robotNamespace>/autoarm</robotNamespace>
</plugin>
```

when i include this to my URDF i can move my arm.But if i change this code into -

```
  <gazebo>
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
  <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
</plugin>
```

I can use the husky_control package to move my husky.So my problem is that  i cant move both my husky and my arm at the same time.This might be a silly question but i am totally lost.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239553/my-custom-made-mobile-manipulator-using-husky-doesnt-move./) by [Dhivin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27282/dhivin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-14**:
This sounds like a gazebo question; you'll probably get a better answer if you ask on the gazebo forums: http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just posted in http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/ .ThankYou.

---

Originally posted by [Dhivin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27282/dhivin/) with karma: 18 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0